# Unable to call WSO2 IS-KM 5.10.0 SCIM2 from WSO2 API Manager 3.1.0 mediation sequence

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

For a service chaining purpose, I have to call SCIM2 Me endpoint from API manager mediation sequence.

POST method to ADD user works fine, but GET/PUT/DELETE methods are not working.

I have provided a code snippet of Get method I'm using in the sequence.

```
        <property name="uri.var.tenantDomain" expression="get-property('tenantDomain')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
        <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="GET" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
        <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
        <property name="messageType" value="application/scim+json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
        <property name="ContentType" value="application/scim+json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
        <property name="Authorization" expression="get-property('Credentials')" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
        <call blocking="true">
            <endpoint>
                <http method="GET" uri-template="https://10.201.8.13:5004/t/{uri.var.tenantDomain}/scim2/Me"/>
            </endpoint>
        </call>
```

On calling the endpoint, I'm getting the below error.

```
{
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error"
    ],
    "detail": "Error from getting the authenticated user",
    "status": "500"
}
```

The same code works fine when I deploy the sequence in EI 6.6.0 for all HTTP Methods.

WIRE Log from ESB

```
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,898] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 >> "GET /test/getUser/me?domain=carbon.super HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,898] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 >> "GET /test/getUser/me?domain=carbon.super HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,899] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 >> "Credentials: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,899] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 >> "Credentials: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,899] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 >> "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,899] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 >> "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,900] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 >> "User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.5[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,900] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 >> "User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.5[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,901] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 >> "Accept: */*[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,901] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 >> "Accept: */*[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,901] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 >> "Postman-Token: fb161eca-313f-4dd6-80b6-ffb98c2e5ffd[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,901] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 >> "Postman-Token: fb161eca-313f-4dd6-80b6-ffb98c2e5ffd[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,902] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 >> "Host: 10.201.8.13:5008[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,902] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 >> "Host: 10.201.8.13:5008[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,902] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,902] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,903] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 >> "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,903] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 >> "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,903] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 >> "Cookie: sails.sid=s%3AKOx3WtbZXUQDOyAeVXwqhLeH17Nltb7v.OG8P3N29zzWPUzQMb1rv%2BGEF%2BXs84%2B2ctxI3OSUFa%2FU[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,903] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 >> "Cookie: sails.sid=s%3AKOx3WtbZXUQDOyAeVXwqhLeH17Nltb7v.OG8P3N29zzWPUzQMb1rv%2BGEF%2BXs84%2B2ctxI3OSUFa%2FU[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,904] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 >> "[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,904] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 >> "[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,907]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - To: /test/getUser/me?domain=carbon.super, MessageID: urn:uuid:04f6da34-36bc-4fd5-9036-a31eb8ec8a73, Direction: request, :: URI :: = /test/getUser/me?domain=carbon.super
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,908]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - To: /test/getUser/me?domain=carbon.super, MessageID: urn:uuid:04f6da34-36bc-4fd5-9036-a31eb8ec8a73, Direction: request, :: ResourceName :: = getUser/me?domain=carbon.super
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,909]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - To: /test/getUser/me?domain=carbon.super, MessageID: urn:uuid:04f6da34-36bc-4fd5-9036-a31eb8ec8a73, Direction: request, :: Credentials :: = Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=, :: tenantDomain :: = carbon.super
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,910]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - To: /test/getUser/me?domain=carbon.super, MessageID: urn:uuid:04f6da34-36bc-4fd5-9036-a31eb8ec8a73, Direction: request, :: Inside :: = getUser/me?domain=carbon.super
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,911]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - To: /test/getUser/me?domain=carbon.super, MessageID: urn:uuid:04f6da34-36bc-4fd5-9036-a31eb8ec8a73, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope>
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,921] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - >> "GET /t/carbon.super/scim2/Me HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,921] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - >> "Content-Type: application/scim+json; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,922] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - >> "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,922] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - >> "User-Agent: Axis2[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,922] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - >> "Host: 10.201.8.13:5004[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,923] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - >> "[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,981] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - << "HTTP/1.1 200 [\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,981] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - << "HTTP/1.1 200 [\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,981] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - << "Location: https://10.201.8.13:5004/scim2/Users/83d21ce2-304d-482c-ab2e-84c14628c1a0[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,982] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - << "Date: Mon, 21 Sep 2020 05:18:35 GMT[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,982] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - << "Content-Type: application/scim+json[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,982] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - << "Content-Length: 2885[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,983] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - << "Server: WSO2 Carbon Server[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,983] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - << "[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,986] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,986] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,986] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 << "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,986] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 << "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,986] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 << "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,986] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 << "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,987] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 << "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,987] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 << "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,987] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 << "Content-Type: application/scim+json; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,987] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 << "Content-Type: application/scim+json; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,987] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 << "Date: Mon, 21 Sep 2020 05:18:35 GMT[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,987] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 << "Date: Mon, 21 Sep 2020 05:18:35 GMT[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,987] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,987] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,988] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,988] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,988] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 << "[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,988] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 << "[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,988] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 << "b45[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,988] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 << "b45[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,989] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 << "0[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,989] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 << "0[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,989] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 << "[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-09-21 10:48:35,989] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-5 << "[\r][\n]"
```

WIRE Log from API Manager

```
[2020-09-21 10:51:00,083] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "GET /engageAPI/user/v1/getUser/me?domain=carbon.super HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:00,086] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Credentials: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=[\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:00,087] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:00,090] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.5[\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:00,091] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Accept: */*[\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:00,092] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Postman-Token: 5bf19c4e-41c2-4434-9ea0-9bb880efb94e[\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:00,092] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Host: localhost:8243[\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:00,092] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br[\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:00,093] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:00,094] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "[\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:00,095] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-2 >> GET /engageAPI/user/v1/getUser/me?domain=carbon.super HTTP/1.1
[2020-09-21 10:51:00,096] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-2 >> Credentials: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
[2020-09-21 10:51:00,096] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-2 >> Content-Type: application/json
[2020-09-21 10:51:00,098] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-2 >> User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.5
[2020-09-21 10:51:00,099] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-2 >> Accept: */*
[2020-09-21 10:51:00,099] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-2 >> Postman-Token: 5bf19c4e-41c2-4434-9ea0-9bb880efb94e
[2020-09-21 10:51:00,100] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-2 >> Host: localhost:8243
[2020-09-21 10:51:00,100] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-2 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
[2020-09-21 10:51:00,101] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-2 >> Connection: keep-alive
[2020-09-21 10:51:00,663]  INFO - LogMediator {api:admin--UserManagement:vv1} To: /engageAPI/user/v1/getUser/me?domain=carbon.super, MessageID: urn:uuid:5231a3ae-ce89-4766-880c-3cd0b2f2f24d, Direction: request, :: URI :: = /engageAPI/user/v1/getUser/me?domain=carbon.super
[2020-09-21 10:51:00,664]  INFO - LogMediator {api:admin--UserManagement:vv1} To: /engageAPI/user/v1/getUser/me?domain=carbon.super, MessageID: urn:uuid:5231a3ae-ce89-4766-880c-3cd0b2f2f24d, Direction: request, :: ResourceName :: = getUser/me?domain=carbon.super
[2020-09-21 10:51:00,666]  INFO - LogMediator {api:admin--UserManagement:vv1} To: /engageAPI/user/v1/getUser/me?domain=carbon.super, MessageID: urn:uuid:5231a3ae-ce89-4766-880c-3cd0b2f2f24d, Direction: request, :: Credentials :: = Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=, :: tenantDomain :: = carbon.super
[2020-09-21 10:51:00,667]  INFO - LogMediator {api:admin--UserManagement:vv1} To: /engageAPI/user/v1/getUser/me?domain=carbon.super, MessageID: urn:uuid:5231a3ae-ce89-4766-880c-3cd0b2f2f24d, Direction: request, :: Inside :: = getUser/me?domain=carbon.super
[2020-09-21 10:51:00,689]  INFO - LogMediator {api:admin--UserManagement:vv1} To: /engageAPI/user/v1/getUser/me?domain=carbon.super, MessageID: urn:uuid:5231a3ae-ce89-4766-880c-3cd0b2f2f24d, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope>
[2020-09-21 10:51:04,090] DEBUG - header >> "GET /t/carbon.super/scim2/Me HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:04,097] DEBUG - header >> "Content-Type: application/scim+json; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:04,097] DEBUG - header >> "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=[\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:04,098] DEBUG - header >> "User-Agent: Axis2[\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:04,099] DEBUG - header >> "Host: 10.201.8.13:5004[\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:04,100] DEBUG - header >> "[\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:04,141] DEBUG - header << "HTTP/1.1 500 [\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:04,143] DEBUG - header << "HTTP/1.1 500 [\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:04,145] DEBUG - header << "Date: Mon, 21 Sep 2020 05:22:20 GMT[\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:04,146] DEBUG - header << "Content-Type: application/scim+json[\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:04,146] DEBUG - header << "Content-Length: 127[\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:04,147] DEBUG - header << "Connection: close[\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:04,147] DEBUG - header << "Server: WSO2 Carbon Server[\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:04,148] DEBUG - header << "[\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:04,183]  INFO - LogMediator {api:admin--UserManagement:vv1} To: https://localhost:5004/t/carbon.super/scim2/Me, MessageID: urn:uuid:5231a3ae-ce89-4766-880c-3cd0b2f2f24d, Direction: request, Payload: {"schemas":["urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error"],"detail":"Error from getting the authenticated user","status":"500"}
[2020-09-21 10:51:04,202] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-2 << HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
[2020-09-21 10:51:04,204] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-2 << Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
[2020-09-21 10:51:04,205] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-2 << Content-Type: application/scim+json; charset=UTF-8
[2020-09-21 10:51:04,209] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-2 << Date: Mon, 21 Sep 2020 05:21:04 GMT
[2020-09-21 10:51:04,212] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-2 << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
[2020-09-21 10:51:04,213] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-2 << Connection: keep-alive
[2020-09-21 10:51:04,216] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error[\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:04,217] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=[\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:04,217] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Content-Type: application/scim+json; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:04,223] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Date: Mon, 21 Sep 2020 05:21:04 GMT[\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:04,225] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:04,226] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:04,227] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "[\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:04,228] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "7f[\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:04,229] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "{"schemas":["urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error"],"detail":"Error from getting the authenticated user","status":"500"}[\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:04,230] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "0[\r][\n]"
[2020-09-21 10:51:04,230] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "[\r][\n]"
```

Can someone guide me on this?

Comment: Have you tried to enable wire logs and see what is being sent to the SCIM call?

Comment: You can enable debug for the following two packages and see more. org.wso2.charon3 & org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim2

Comment: @JuniorRibeiro - I have added wire logs. From ESB I'm getting 200 OK but from API manager I'm getting 500.

Comment: @Sajith - I'm unable to find the logger packages in log4j2.properties. Can you guide me?

Comment: Add these two loggers
`logger.org-charon.name = org.wso2.charon3
logger.org-charon.level = DEBUG

logger.org-scim2.name = org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim2
logger.org-scim2.level = DEBUG`
then update the loggers list with `org-scim2, org-charon`

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the X509Certificate or certificate-based authentication is enabled in both APIM and IS versions. So APIM sends the certificate attribute name and since IS support X509Certificate based authentication IS gives priority to this. Since EI not support this there is no issue with ESB. In order to fix this, we can disable or reduce the priority of X509Certificate based authentication in IS.

Adding following configuration can reduce the priority and get this working. So add this to <IS_KM>/repository/conf/deployment.toml

```
[[event_listener]]
id="x509Certificate_auth"
name="org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.service.handler.impl.ClientCertificateBasedAuthenticationHandler"
order="1000"
type="org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.handler.AbstractIdentityMessageHandler"
```