# WSO2 API Manager 3.1.0 Unable to call GET HTTP Method from Mediation sequence

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Unable to call GET APIs through the Mediation sequence in API Manager 3.1.0. The GET API call is behaving as a POST with No Body.
My code is below.

```
            <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="GET" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
            <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
            <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
            <property name="ContentType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
            <property name="Authorization" expression="get-property('Credentials')" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
            <property name="uri.var.tenantDomain" expression="get-property('tenantDomain')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" action="remove" scope="axis2"/>
            <call blocking="true">
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="GET" uri-template="https://localhost:9443/t/{uri.var.tenantDomain}/api/users/v1/me/challenges"/>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
```

This is for challenge questions, whenever the URI is the same for POST and other Methods, only POST is working fine and not PUT, GET and DELETE.
The same issue was observed with SCIM2 APIs too, but I changed from SCIM2 to SOAP Admin services to resolve the issue. OTher GET APIs for Recovery are working fine. Only when the URI is the same for GET/PUT/DELETE and POST, this behavior is observed from mediation sequence

WIRE LOGS:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,543] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - >> "GET /t/jio.eva.hdfc.com/api/users/v1/me/challenges HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,543] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - >> "GET /t/jio.eva.hdfc.com/api/users/v1/me/challenges HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,544] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - >> "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,544] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - >> "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,544] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - >> "Accept: application/json[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,544] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - >> "Accept: application/json[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,545] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - >> "Authorization: Basic XXXXXXX[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,545] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - >> "Authorization: Basic XXXXXXX[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,545] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - >> "User-Agent: Axis2[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,545] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - >> "User-Agent: Axis2[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,545] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - >> "Host: 10.201.8.13:5004[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,545] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - >> "Host: 10.201.8.13:5004[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,546] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - >> "[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,546] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - >> "[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,563] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - << "HTTP/1.1 500 [\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,563] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - << "HTTP/1.1 500 [\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,564] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - << "HTTP/1.1 500 [\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,564] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - << "HTTP/1.1 500 [\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,564] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - << "Date: Thu, 24 Sep 2020 10:59:07 GMT[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,564] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - << "Date: Thu, 24 Sep 2020 10:59:07 GMT[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,564] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - << "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,564] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - << "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,565] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,565] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,565] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - << "Connection: close[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,565] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - << "Connection: close[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,565] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - << "Server: WSO2 Carbon Server[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,565] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - << "Server: WSO2 Carbon Server[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,566] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - << "[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,566] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - << "[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,566] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.content} - << "b"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,566] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.content} - << "b"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,566] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.content} - << "4"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,566] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.content} - << "4"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,567] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.content} - << "[\r]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,567] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.content} - << "[\r]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,567] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.content} - << "[\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,567] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.content} - << "[\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,567] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.content} - << "{"code":"SE-50000","message":"Unexpected Processing Error.","description":"Server encountered an error while serving the request.","traceId":"46947467-c363-4cb4-87d7-d2e37c039b3a"}"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,567] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.content} - << "{"code":"SE-50000","message":"Unexpected Processing Error.","description":"Server encountered an error while serving the request.","traceId":"46947467-c363-4cb4-87d7-d2e37c039b3a"}"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,568] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.content} - << "[\r]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,568] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.content} - << "[\r]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,568] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.content} - << "[\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,568] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.content} - << "[\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,568] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.content} - << "0"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,568] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.content} - << "0"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,569] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.content} - << "[\r]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,569] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.content} - << "[\r]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,569] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.content} - << "[\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,569] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.content} - << "[\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,569] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.content} - << "[\r]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,569] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.content} - << "[\r]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,569] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.content} - << "[\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,569] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.content} - << "[\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,570] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - << "[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,570] DEBUG {httpclient.wire.header} - << "[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-09-24 16:29:07,571]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - To: https://10.201.8.13:5004/t/jio.eva.hdfc.com/api/users/v1/me/challenges, MessageID: urn:uuid:a0a2832b-29cf-41dd-bc70-4d9da1721f3e, Direction: request, HTTP_SC = 500, Payload: {"code":"SE-50000","message":"Unexpected Processing Error.","description":"Server encountered an error while serving the request.","traceId":"46947467-c363-4cb4-87d7-d2e37c039b3a"}
```

***The same code works in EI 6.6.0***

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the following[1] and the issue is due to the IS-KM certificate-based authenticator.

[1] [Unable to call WSO2 IS-KM 5.10.0 SCIM2 from WSO2 API Manager 3.1.0 mediation sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63955136/unable-to-call-wso2-is-km-5-10-0-scim2-from-wso2-api-manager-3-1-0-mediation-seq)